# Adding new product with category tree - specific price problems

Tags: prestashop, action, bulk, price

I installed an add-on for bulk action (called ba_importer v 1.1.24), I upload an Excel file with my data and create a group of products.

I can set the categories' tree or manually add ID of main categories and associated. I tried with no luck to use the tree features (like Home/Products/etc) and so I use all the ID of main category and all the associated. The result is a product with the correct categories set, but with no specific price from the customer group linked to a category.

I tried to edit a single product, remove all categories and set it one by one (set one, save, set one, save etc.) and then the specific price from the group linked to a category appears to the product.

Is there a better solution? I'm thinking about make a personal PHP page that reads an Excel file and sets all the information about the product, but I'm scared to face the same problem with the specific price.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as "category-related specific price",
if you have specific prices tied to customer groups , these are created as a result of the add/update product action with **ps_specific_price** DB entries having **id_group** with your restricted ID.

It is likely that the bulk module acts directly with DB queries to speed up things and bypasses this operation, I've seen this behaviour with those kind of modules in the past.

Since you are talking of a paid add-on, I would definitely seek help from the developer.